# Build Qt5 with Cmake in Yocto

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, embedded-linux, yocto

We are cross-compiling our Qt5 application within Yocto/Bitbake using CMake for Cortex ARM 9.

No matter what I do, I can't get Cmake to find the required `Qt5Config.cmake` config file.

The error message is well known out there:

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:71 (find_package):
 By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
 asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
 CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
 the following names:

     Qt5Config.cmake
     qt5-config.cmake

 Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
 to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
 separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The recipy seems to be fine so far. I depend Qt and use Cmake by:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += " qtconnectivity "
inherit pkgconfig cmake
```

Unfortunately I am uncertain about two things:

1. When I build Yocto (on 2 cores), why is bitbake building the `qt5` packages before or at the same time as my faulty recipe? Shouldn't the dependency sort this out? I also tried to use `DEPENDS` instead of `RDEPENDS`, but that doesn't make a difference.
2. I don't know in which sysroots Qt is being installed. When I do `find . -name Qt5Config.cmake` I find so many places. One of the places looks a bit more promising than the others. It is: `./tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl/qtbase/usr/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake`. But still, shouldn't the Qt libs be in the sysroot of "my recipe"?

So, after all, I try to let `CMake` know the location of `Qt5Config.cmake`. I try by setting

```
export Qt5_DIR = "/home/vagrant/build/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl/qtbase/usr/lib/cmake/Qt5/"
```

in the recipe and can confirm with a CMake output that it knows the path `Qt5_DIR`. Also setting the path in CMake (with `set(Qt5_DIR ...)`) doesn't help.

The path remains unknown. Even if I would be happy now to make CMake understand where Qt5 is - there seems to be a misconfiguration, as I would assume that Qt should be known to my recipe automatically.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got around to answering. I had the same issue for awhile and discovered the [cmake_qt5](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/blob/master/classes/cmake_qt5.bbclass) bitbake class.

Using this class in place of `cmake` should populate all the necessary flags needed to use Qt5 with CMake in the Yocto Project.

Comment: Thanks so much @mascoj! This solved the problem nicely.

Comment: The cmake_qt5 recipe also shows how to use the `RDEPENDS_prepend` dependency. I didn't know about that - this solves my point "1." of not understanding, why the dependent package is built in parallel.

Comment: How do you go about this use the toolchain? I don't seem to have problems on Yocto Zeus, but I have the same problem as OP on Yocto Sumo.

Comment: @Logan This solution is the same between Zeus and Sumo.  `cmake_qt5.bbclass ` has been provided by the meta-qt5 layer since daisy

Comment: @mascoj Maybe I was too hasty with my comment. In Zeus I am just using the default yocto toolchain. In Sumo I am using the Boot2Qt variant of the yocto toolchain. They both provide `cmake`, but they do not behave the same under these circumstances.

Comment: @Logan I think that probably deserves it's own question post about Boot2Qt as it's a custom yocto toolchain. Just double check you are using `cmake_qt5` and not just `cmake`

Comment: @mascoj I totally agree. Haven't gotten around to making a post as it's not blocking my work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to inherit class **cmake_qt5** and make sure that you assigned **do_install**() like that

```
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)

# Unable to find any files that looked like license statements. Check the accompanying
# documentation and source headers and set LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM accordingly.
#
# NOTE: LICENSE is being set to "CLOSED" to allow you to at least start building - if
# this is not accurate with respect to the licensing of the software being built (it
# will not be in most cases) you must specify the correct value before using this
# recipe for anything other than initial testing/development!
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""
S="${WORKDIR}" 
SRC_URI = "file://login.tar"
DEPENDS += "qtbase wayland"
# NOTE: unable to map the following CMake package dependencies: Qt QT
inherit cmake
inherit cmake_qt5
# Specify any options you want to pass to cmake using EXTRA_OECMAKE:
EXTRA_OECMAKE = ""

do_install(){
    install -d ${D}${sbindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/build/login_system ${D}${sbindir}/login_system
}
```